# How to Validate ui data with rest api responses

Tags: java, rest, selenium-webdriver, assert, rest-assured

I need to validate my ui data and api responses are same,

here is my code I tried,

```
private ValidateContentPage cp = new ValidateContentPage();

public void getTitle() {
        String UITitle = driver.findElement(titlepage).getText();
        System.out.println(UITitle);
        Assert.assertEquals(UITitle, cp.getAPICall(),"Passed");
    }
```

here im getting my api responses,

```
public class ValidateContentPage {
    
    public common cm = new common();
    public Properties prop;
    
    public void baseURI() {
        prop = cm.getProperties("./src/test/API/IndiaOne/propertyfile/EndpointURL.properties");
        RestAssured.baseURI = prop.getProperty("baseURI");
    }
    
    public String getAPICall() {
        
        objectpojo ps = given().expect().defaultParser(Parser.JSON).when().get(prop.getProperty("resources")).as(objectpojo.class, cm.getMapper());
        int number = ps.getPosts().size();
        System.out.println(number);
        System.out.println(ps.getPosts().get(0).getTitle());
        return ps.getPosts().get(0).getTitle();
    }
```

If i validate both using testng assertion it throwing null pointer exception, anyone help me on how to validate my ui data and api responses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your ValidateContentPage  from `@Test` itself or from `@BeforeTest`

```
@Test
public void getTitle() {
        String UITitle = driver.findElement(titlepage).getText();
        System.out.println(UITitle);
        ValidateContentPage cp = new ValidateContentPage();
        Assert.assertEquals(UITitle, cp.getAPICall(),"Passed");
    }
```